# Safari Chrome Randomly Timeout, Firefox Never

Tags: google-chrome, safari, timeout

Thanks in Advanced,
Safari and Chrome are randomly timing out / freezing / hanging.  This happens randomly on random pages.  I can click refresh about 5 times and then the pages load quickly.  If I let it try to download, the page get the server is not responding error.  The pages always load very fast with Firefox.  I typically see the problem after I am logged in the backend which involves sessions / cookies.  Cookies are enabled on both browsers.  IE also works but is slower than firefox.  I am not sure what is wrong with the code that is causing the problem.

Safari 6.0
/
Chrome 21.0
Firefox 15.0
on Mac 10.8.1
I have also had problems on windows xp with chrome.  Very few times I had lost my session and had to relogin on IE 6.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an `EXPIRES` header:

> Web pages are becoming increasingly complex with more scripts, style
>   sheets, images, and Flash on them. A first-time visit to a page may
>   require several HTTP requests to load all the components. By using
>   Expires headers these components become cacheable, which avoids
>   unnecessary HTTP requests on subsequent page views. Expires headers
>   are most often associated with images, but they can and should be used
>   on all page components including scripts, style sheets, and Flash.

and configuring Entity Tags:

> Entity tags (ETags) are a mechanism web servers and the browser use to
>   determine whether a component in the browser's cache matches one on
>   the origin server. Since ETags are typically constructed using
>   attributes that make them unique to a specific server hosting a site,
>   the tags will not match when a browser gets the original component
>   from one server and later tries to validate that component on a
>   different server.

I got the information above using [YSlow](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ninejjcohidippngpapiilnmkgllmakh) on Chrome.

Comment: Hi Alex, I just just added the expired header to my htaccess file, and my site has sped up.  But I am still having timeouts, though less.  I used the following code http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-compression.html  Any other great ideas?  Thanks again

Comment: It turned out to be a ssl certificate problem on the web hosting server.  I switched hosts and now no problem.